# SNPP Kannel Redis: How to make them fully work?

Tags: c, ubuntu, suse, kannel

I have ubuntu in my computer installed. I built redis from this [site](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart)  and installed it in a directory. Next i downloaded Kannel from this [site](http://www.kannel.org/which) ****** in a stable release (1.4.4) and configured my kanel.conf as mentioned in this [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufQPm.png)

I also installed snpp and am running smsbox. When I need to send an sms I do it using `127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms` which communicates perfectly with kannel, snpp. However, even though redis is prompted to be connected with Kannel, Redis table does not populate.

I need help please, whoever knows please answer me. It is of great importance to me.

Possible hint: Redis needs configuration so that it works with CRUD. I have searched through internet in vein. I found poor even no documentation on this issue. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your kannel configuration, mostly the redis section?

Answer (score 0):

Did you placed all other Kannel configurations properly?